# Pinterest Authorization Failed for business account

Tags: pinterest

When our app tries to get data about Pinterest user with business account, we get the following response:

> 401 Unauthorized (Authorization Failed)

We are using valid access token which is checked here: [Pinterest Token Debugger](https://developers.pinterest.com/tools/token-debugger/).
However, it works fine for personal accounts

Endpoint for getting user details is: [https://api.pinterest.com/v1/me/?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&fields=first_name%2Cid%2Cusername%2Clast_name](https://api.pinterest.com/v1/me/?access_token=%3CACCESS_TOKEN%3E&fields=first_name%2Cid%2Cusername%2Clast_name)

Are we doing something wrong or this is a bug?